# SUM and SELECT ALL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need a correction please

```
SELECT *, SUN(mytable2.quantite)
FROM mytable1 
INNER JOIN mytable2 
ON mytable1.id = mytable2.id_table_article
```

I want to select all columns and SUM one column. How I can do that please ?

I have a problem because I think `SUM` works with `ExecuteScalar` and `SELECT *` works with `ExecuteReader()`
:( how I cant fusion this result because I need to show this result at on my listview so I need one request :/
I work with SQLIte

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Using `*` and `SUM()` in the same select doesn't make sense -- one gets all the columns and the other supposes aggregation.

Comment: The dimmension of the result would not make sense, all the columns' values will be shown except for one column that will show only a value (the sum of all the values of the column).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want every column from `mytable1` and the corresponding sum from `mytable2`.  If so, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.quantite)
        FROM mytable2 t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id_table_article
       ) as quantite
FROM mytable1 t1;
```

Comment: Thanks, can i write this request like this:

SELECT table.* (SELECT SUM(table2.quantite) WHERE table1.id = table2.id_table_article) FROM table1;


is this correct ?

Comment: Not at all.  At the very least, it is missing a comma, a `from` clause, and has an incorrect table alias.  The version in my answer should work.

Comment: Other think please, when i write:

                    MessageBox.Show(reader["nameofcolomn of table1"].ToString());
i get a result but when i write
                    MessageBox.Show(reader["nameofcolomn of table2"].ToString());

i get a error :'(

Comment: @thedarkside . . . Use the alias defined in the `select` statement to get the column that you want.

Comment: can you give me please a exemple ?
i try to add quantity in
SELECT t1.*, t2.quantity 
       (SELECT SUM(t2.quantite)
        FROM mytable2 t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id_table_article
       ) as quantite
FROM mytable1 t1;

but still not work :/
help me please
i just want show the sum of quantity of my table2 in a message box

Comment: look this is my truc code:

this is my request:
sql = "SELECT t1.*, (SELECT SUM(t2.id_qte) FROM associationdepotarticle t2 WHERE t1.fusiontable = t2.fusiontable) as id_qte FROM articletable t1";

its work fine now but i can't do that

MessageBox(reader["t2.id"].ToString());

i get a error :/

i think that ill select all from my Table2 but how i can do that and keep my sum function

help me please

Comment: That is a question about the application layer you are using.  Ask *another* question, with the relevant information, although I suspect you only need `reader["id_qte"]` to get what you want.

Comment: thanks its work but if i want show other then id_qte, if i want show id for exemple ?
 
look this is my truc code: this is my request: sql = "SELECT t1.*, (SELECT SUM(t2.id_qte) FROM associationdepotarticle t2 WHERE t1.fusiontable = t2.fusiontable) as id_qte FROM articletable t1"; its work fine now but i can't do that MessageBox(reader["t2.id"].ToString()); i get a error :/ i think that ill select all from my Table2 but how i can do that and keep my sum function help me please